# How can I convert one row with a total population column and total successes column to multiple rows of successes and failures?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataframe set up with an ID, TotalPopulation, and TotalSuccesses. I need to translate this into multiple rows per ID, with the total rows per ID = TotalPopulation of that ID. I then need to attach a "success" column, 1 or 0, and assign the correct number of success values according to the TotalSuccesses column.

Here is a small example:

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 3, 1], 
                   ['B', 5, 2], 
                   ['C', 4, 2]], 
                  columns = ['ID', 'TotalPopulation', 'TotalSuccesses'])

desired_df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 1], 
                           ['A', 0], 
                           ['A', 0], 
                           ['B', 1], 
                           ['B', 1],
                           ['B', 0],
                           ['B', 0],
                           ['B', 0],
                           ['C', 1],
                           ['C', 1],
                           ['C', 0],
                           ['C', 0],], 
                        columns = ['ID', 'Success'])

df
Out[20]: 
  ID  TotalPopulation  TotalSuccesses
0  A                3               1
1  B                5               2
2  C                4               2

desired_df
Out[21]: 
   ID  Success
0   A        1
1   A        0
2   A        0
3   B        1
4   B        1
5   B        0
6   B        0
7   B        0
8   C        1
9   C        1
10  C        0
11  C        0
```

I've attempted expanding the dataset via the following method, but due to the size of my dataset, I am not sure if it will ever finish running. After that, I couldn't find a good solution to assign the correct number of "successes". So, if this is what I need to run to make it duplicate, I still need some help figuring out how to assign those "successes"

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([df.ix[idx] 
                       for idx in df.index 
                       for _ in range(int(df.ix[idx]['TotalPopulation']))]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Any guidance is appreciated!